# Использовал freopen для stdin, как связать стандартный поток ввода обратно с консолью?

Tags: c++, c

Разбираю файл в массив с помощью freopen, но не понимаю как вернуть стандартный поток ввода обратно, может кто с таким сталкивался. Приложение консольное.

```
    bool LoadData(const string &fn)
    {
        bool stat(0);
        if ( freopen(fn.c_str(), "r", stdin) )
        {
            stat = 1;
            ...

        }
        fclose (stdin);
        return stat;
    }


    int main()
    {
        ...
        LoadData(fn);
        ...
        cin >> s; // это не работает
        ...
        system ("pause"); // это тоже не работает т.к. завязано на stdin
        return 0;
    }
```

Вообщем решение для windows: `freopen("CON", "r", stdin);`
удалять вопрос не буду, может кому пригодится.

Comment: Перенесите ваше решение в ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел.

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Вы применяете глобальное решение ля локальной проблемы — вдруг другой поток захочет воспользоваться stdin'ом? Почему бы вам не параметризировать входным потоком процедуру чтения данных?

Comment: @VladD это самый быстрый способ чтения файла.  а что такое "параметризировать входным потоком процедуру чтения данных" я незнаю.

Comment: @xttz: Ну, там где процедура LoadData использует `cin`, использовать `istream s`, который передавать в эту процедуру в качестве параметра. Если вы покажете код LoadData, будет понятнее.

Comment: @VladD вот исходник https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRSky1dZxT-cDN0dDRQVkRIbUU/view?usp=sharing после связи файла с потоком ввода использую getchar(). ifstream или fopen проигрывают этому способу от 2 раз, для больших файлов это существенно.

Comment: @xttz: Ну, откройте файл в начале через `FILE* f = fopen(...)`, и читайте через `getc(f)` вместо `getchar()`. Вы хотите сказать, что вы пробовали это, и получается **медленнее**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте-ка я вынесу из комментариев.

Вам нужно поменять функцию `LoadData` так, чтобы она читала не из `stdin`, а из данного файла.

```
bool LoadData(const string &fn, Dup &tmp)
{
    tmp = {0,0,0,0,"",fn};
    bool stat(0);
    // if ( freopen(fn.c_str(), "r", stdin) )
    FILE* f = fopen(fn.c_str(), "r");
    if (f)
    {
```

плюс поменяйте везде `getchar()` на `getc(f)`, плюс в конце `fclose(stdin)` на `fclose(f)`.

---

Ещё по коду: вы совершенно зря объявили

```
char t = getchar();
```

Дело в том, что `getchar` (а также `getc`) возвращают для конца файла значение EOF, которое не равно ни одному из значений, помещающихся в `char`. В текущей версии кода, если вдруг значение `(char)EOF` встретится в файле, работа функции прекратится. Используйте `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем решение для windows: `freopen("CON", "r", stdin);`

Comment: И что произойдет, если программу вызывали `a.exe < x.txt` ? / В \*nix я бы сохранил stdin в `int oldfd = fileno(stdin)); FILE *save = fdopen(oldfd, "r");` а после "проблемной" функции похожим образом восстановил stdin c oldfd. / Но, можно ли такие штуки делать в винде?

Comment: Эм.. Это _было решением_ в Borland CPP 3.1. В Visual Studio 2005 это не работало. Почти уверен, что в более новых это тоже не работает. В чём ты проверял?

Comment: @Qwertiy gcc 5.1.0 сборка mingw64